# Significado de "ainda bem"!

Tags: significado, expressões

Qual o significado de **ainda bem**?

Por exemplo: houve um acidente, mas ninguém se machucou. Ainda bem!

Isso significa "que bom" ou outra coisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na frase que você citou, significa "felizmente", "que bom", "graças a Deus".

- Ainda bem que eu trouxe o guarda-chuva.
- Ela não soube de nada?  Puxa, ainda bem.
- Olha só o tamanho da fila. Ainda bem que já compramos os ingressos.

> - [**ainda bem**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ainda%20bem) - felizmente.

Nota: "graças a Deus", nos dias de hoje e na maioria das vezes, não tem nenhuma conotação religiosa e significa apenas "felizmente" ou "que bom".

Answer (score 1):

No Brasil, quando dizemos "ainda bem", é praticamente um "Gog Bless". Seria um "GRAÇAS A DEUS" que estão todos bem. Principalmente os mais religiosos, ainda utilizam bastante "gracas a Deus", e, dependendo da gravidade do acidente/saúde, o "graças a Deus" é dito com mais frequência mesmo por aqueles que não são tão religiosos. Digamos que um "ainda bem" também tenha a ver com essa gravidade:

- "Ele caiu mas não quebrou o pé" - "Ainda bem!"
- "Ele levou um tiro mas já está melhor" - "Graças a Deus!"